# Why is key in kwargs dropped if positional argument with same name present?

Tags: python, keyword-argument

I just ran into this behavior that surprised me:

```
def my_func(a=4, **kwargs):
    print kwargs
```

Demo:

```
>>> my_func(a=5, b=6)
{'b': 6}  # I was expecting {'a' : 4, 'b' : 6}
          # Maybe {'a' : 5, 'b' : 6}
```

Also, I would not be to surprised if I got:

`SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated`

as in

```
>>> my_func(a=4, a=5)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated
```

or `TypeError: my_func() got multiple values for keyword argument 'a'`

as in

```
>>> my_func(a=4, **{'a' : 5, 'b' : 6})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: my_func() got multiple values for keyword argument 'a'
```

What rules does python follow to drop keyword 'a'?

Maybe I missing something obvious, or a crucial term, but I could not find the solution via searching.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`a` isn't being dropped, it's just not getting included in `**kwargs`, because you explicitly defined it in the function definition. So If I edit your original example:

```
def my_func(a=4, **kwargs):
    print kwargs
    print a
```

And then test it:

```
>>> my_func(a=5, b=7)
{'b': 7}
5
```

The `**kwargs` argument is used to gather up optional keyword arguments given in a function call that **aren't explicitly included in the function definition**. Since you included `a=4` in the definition of `my_func`, it won't get included in `**kwargs`.

This is mentioned in the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments) (emphasis mine):

> When a final formal parameter of the form **name is present, it
>   receives a dictionary (see [Mapping Types — dict](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping)) containing all
>   keyword arguments **except for those corresponding to a formal parameter.**

Comment: I know that `a` is still there, but is no longer in `kwargs` dictionary. So if I pass `kwargs` further down `a` will no longer be there.

Comment: I am mostly concerned about the rule python is following, would be accurate: if an argument is explicitly specified in the function definition, it is dropped from the kwargs.

Comment: @Akavall Yes, that's accurate. I edited my answer to include a link to the Python documentation that states this.

Comment: kwargs only gathers up *additional* key-value pairings into the dictionary, after all other parameters have been bound to arguments.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Python's mapping of arguments to parameters includes handling any of the argument expressed as "arg=value" expressions even if they are out of order.  This removes the "arg=value" pair from inclusion in the **kwargs dictionary (which catches all names/keys that weren't among the parameter list).

Consider this trivial example:

```
#/usr/bin/python
def foo(a, **d):
    print 'a=', a
    print 'd=', d

foo(z=1)
## TypeError: foo() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
foo(a=1)
## a= 1
## d= {}
foo(z=1, a=2, b=3)
## a= 2
## d= {'z':1, 'b':3}
foo(a=1, z=2, 3)
## SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg
```

Note that I've implemented "foo" with a positional parameter and without a default argument thereto; it has a default then "a=" will still be picked out of the argument list, if it appears, but its omission won't raise an exception and it will be "None" or whatever you supplied as the default argument.

It's sometimes useful to make the distinction between arguments and parameters.  This distinction is rarely adhered to in common documentation and online discussion ... so it can be a bit academic.  However, a parameter is a name, supplied in the definition/header of a function and into which arguments are bound when the function is called.  Parameter = Placeholder, argument = actual value during the call.  Sometimes making this distinction can make discussions, such as this one, less confusing.

One point of possible confusion arises when talking about the `def` statement itself.  In my statement: `def foo(a=None, **d)` a and d are parameters, while `a=None` and `**d` are arguments (to the define statement itself).  This can be particularly confusing when intermediate Python programmers first encounter the semantics of a mutable object instantiated as an argument in a function definition: `def foo(mydict={}, mylist=[]):` ... this can have some interesting semantics when called with and without arguments.  The key to understanding this sort of function is that mydict and mylist are bound to objects which are instantiated when the function is defined.  Those objects are only visible when the function is called without arguments for those parameters, and those parameters are bound to other objects when the function is called with arguments in those positions.  (As you can see, that concept becomes almost impossible to express when using the term "argument" interchangeably with "parameter").